# Create stored procedure from set of SQL - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a set of SQL like and I would like to convert it to function or a stored procedure in an automated way:

```
create table test as
select * from test1;

DELETE FROM test
WHERE
    e_id LIKE '%00-01';



MERGE INTO test tgt USING (
  SELECT 
    LISTAGG(e_val, ':') WITHIN GROUP(
      ORDER BY 
        e_id
    ) OVER(PARTITION BY unique_id, line) e_val, 
    CASE WHEN e_id IN ('BHT03-02', 'BHT03-03') THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END del 
  FROM 
    test 
  WHERE 
    e_id IN (
      'ABC03-01'
    )
) src ON (
  tgt.unique_id = src.unique_id 
  AND tgt.line = src.line 
  AND tgt.e_id = src.e_id
)
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
UPDATE 
SET 
  tgt.e_value = src.e_value DELETE 
WHERE 
  src.del = 'Y';
```

Is there any easy way of creating a stored procedure or function using this?

Comment: What do you want to automate? Presumably you're looking to pass in parameters for values in the CASE clause and the subquery WHERE clause. What about the WHERE LIKE in the DELETE statement? Is the creation of the `test` table part of the procedure?

Comment: I don't want to pass parameters at this point. Just need a stored procedure which can execute my different SQL. Creating test table would be part of the procedure.

Comment: I want to create stored procedure without writing execute immediate.

Comment: You can't create a table in PL/SQL (or execute any DDL) without using execute immediate. Also, if you're creating a table in the stored procedure it won't exist at compile time, so you can't compile the MERGE  statement. Which means that would have to be dynamic SQL too. That's messy. I suggest you re-examine your requirement to creating the table on the fly.

Comment: Ok, I'm afraid creating table is important for me. Maybe the way is to write stored procedure manually.

Comment: Put all of them in a SQL file and execute it from a Shell script through SQL* Plus.

Comment: Can I call sql file from a stored procedure?

Comment: Yes you could create a scheduler program to call the shell script. http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_schedule_unix_shell_scripts_using_dbms_scheduler.htm and it may run at predefined time/intervals. It will then be purely  "automatic" as you wished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just enclose this code between procedure definition

example

```
create or replace procedure do_some_work
as

begin
  --paste your code here;
end;
```

you can run this procedure by calling it :

```
EXEC do_some_work;
```

Comment: Don't I need execute immediate?

Comment: sure you need execute immediate to run your sql statements inside the procedure